# How can one access a hidden changeset from a Mercurial server?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-phases

I have a clone of a remote repository which supports Mercurial topics.

In this version of hg-evolve when the changesets are rebased (for instance) they are hidden.

**I need to access the exact working directory at a hidden changeset which I do not have on my local clone.** I have verified that other people's clones do have that changeset available via the `--hidden` flag of most mercurial commands.

I have tried:

`hg --hidden clone`
`hg --hidden pull`

but neither seem to have any affect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloning the repository using **`hg clone --stream`** will include the hidden changesets, if they're available on the server.